# Auto-fill for testing data after DictVectorizer and fit_transform

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In Sklearn, for training data's dictionary, I have the full-length vectors, transformed from the original dict, like [1,0,0,0,0]. (using DictVectorizer and fit_transform.)

```
vec = DictVectorizer(sparse=True)
data = vec.fit_transform(dict_list)
```

However, in the testing data, due to the limited sample number, I do not have the full-length vectors transformed from dict, like [0,0,0,1].

Is these anything that can help, automatically fills in the testing data for the missing vector columns (to be 0)?

Answer (score 0):

On the testing side as well, all you do is:

```
test_data = vec.transform(test_dict_list)
```